# Let $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be an orthogonal linear map with determinant $1$. Show that $A^* \circ \star = \star \circ A^*$

Tags: differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

> Let $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be an orthogonal linear map with determinant $1$. Show that $$A^* \circ \star = \star \circ A^* : \mathrm{Alt}^k(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathrm{Alt}^{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$ for $0 \le k \le n.$

My working so far. Let $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ be an orthogonal base for $\mathbb{R}^n$. We then get an orthogonal base $\{\varepsilon_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge\varepsilon_{i_k} \mid 1\le i_1 < \dots < i_k \le n \}$ for $\mathrm{Alt}^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Now since $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ we know that $A^* : \mathrm{Alt}^k(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathrm{Alt}^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a multiplication by $\det(A)$. For $v_1,\dots,v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have $$\begin{align*}A^*(\star(\varepsilon_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge\varepsilon_{i_k}))(v_1,\dots,v_k)&= A^*(\varepsilon_{i_{k+1}} \wedge \dots \wedge\varepsilon_{i_{n}})(v_1,\dots,v_k)  \\ &= \det(A)\varepsilon_{i_{k+1}} \wedge \dots \wedge\varepsilon_{i_{n}}(A(e_1),\dots,A(e_k)) \\ &= \varepsilon_{i_{k+1}} \wedge \dots \wedge\varepsilon_{i_{n}}(A(e_1),\dots,A(e_k)).\end{align*}$$

Similarly $$\begin{align*} \star(A^*(\varepsilon_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge\varepsilon_{i_k}))(v_1,\dots,v_k) &=  \star(\det(A)\varepsilon_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge\varepsilon_{i_k}(A(e_1),\dots,A(e_k))) \\&= \star(\varepsilon_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge\varepsilon_{i_k}(A(e_1),\dots, A(e_k)) \\&= \varepsilon_{i_{k+1}} \wedge \dots \wedge\varepsilon_{i_n}(A(e_1),\dots,A(e_k))\end{align*}$$

which would imply equality. My issue is two things. Firstly I'm not using orthogonality at all here which probably means I'm doing something wrong. Second issue is that is it enough to show that the equality holds for basis elements $\varepsilon_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge\varepsilon_{i_k}$ and argue that linearity will give the general case?

Comment: Is $A^{\ast}$ simply supposed to be the map induced by $A$ on $Alt^k$? In this case, there also is no reason for this map to be multiplication by $\det(A)$ unless $k=n$. It also appears you're using $e$, $\epsilon$ and $v$ inconsistently and that makes this harder to follow. Lastly, is your $Alt^k$ supposed to be alternating $k$-forms or alternating $k$-linear maps?

Comment: Your notation is completely mysterious.

Comment: Which part seems mysterious/inconsistent? Please let me know and I see if I can clarify. I general I think that if $L : V \to V$ is a linear map, then $L^*$ is a multiplication by $\det(L)$. However it seems that I'm wrong here as Thorgott stated. @Thorgott

Comment: @P.Lawrence Please let me know which part is not clear and I see if I can elaborate on what I'm trying to state.

Comment: And yes $A^*$ is the induced map on $\mathrm{Alt}^k$. The source of my confusion with the multiplication by $\det(A)$ seems to result from thinking that this is true even when $k \ne n$. @Thorgott

Comment: To see what would go wrong if $A$ is not orthogonal, try $n=2$, $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $k=1$.

Comment: How do you propose trying this, am I in the correct direction by considering this with basis elements and then using linearity to get the general case? @ArcticChar

Comment: I am suggesting that you first try some simple cases and see what is exactly happening.

Comment: Given your setting we have that $A^* : \mathrm{Alt}^1(\mathbb{R}^2) \to \mathrm{Alt}^1(\mathbb{R}^2) $ and $\star : \mathrm{Alt}^1(\mathbb{R}^2) \to \mathrm{Alt}^{2-1}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. If $\{\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2\}$ is a basis for $\mathrm{Alt}^1(\mathbb{R}^2) = (\mathbb{R}^2)^*$, then for $\omega \in (\mathbb{R}^2)^*$ we have $$A^*(\star(\omega))= A^*\left(\star\left(a_1\varepsilon_1+ a_2\varepsilon_2\right)\right) = a_1a_2 \cdot A^*(\star(\varepsilon_1) + \star(\varepsilon_2))$$

Comment: which gives $$a_1a_2 \cdot A^*(\star(\varepsilon_1) + \star(\varepsilon_2)) = a_1a_2\cdot A^*(\star(\varepsilon_1)) + A^*(\star(\varepsilon_2))$$ and as $\star(\varepsilon_1)=\varepsilon_2$ and $\star(\varepsilon_2)=\varepsilon_1$ one has that $$A^*(\star(\omega))(v_1)=a_1a_2 \cdot A^*(\varepsilon_2)(v_1) + A^*(\varepsilon_1)(v_1)$$

Comment: By writing $\omega = a_1\varepsilon_1 + a_2\varepsilon_2 \in \mathrm{Alt}^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and using linearity. @TedShifrin

Comment: @Thomas The mistake is clear in what you wrote two comments above. $A^*(\star(a_1\epsilon_1)) = a_1 A^*(\star\epsilon_1) = a_1 A^*(\epsilon_2)$, assuming that $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ is the orthonormal dual basis. How does $a_2$ appear here "using linearity"? $a_1$ pulls out of the $\epsilon_1$ term and $a_2$ pulls out of the $\epsilon_2$ term; linearity does not result in their product!